# PDF asp.net Preview

Tags: asp.net, pdf, preview

Does anyone know of any way that we can preview pdf documents in a asp.net web application, preferably on a mouse over event? This may involve some javascript to complete but any control that would allow for a pdf to pop up and disappear on command would be helpful.

Thank you  in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found this free service online that could be useful:

http://issuu.com/smartlook

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on whether the client has Adobe Reader installed on their machine, and you should have a fallback incase they don't.

At any rate, see this SO question for details:
[Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)